# Trigger workflow from different branch

Tags: github-actions

I have a two workflow files in my `main` (default) branch. Let's say `workflow-1.yml` is for `main` itself and `workflow-2.yml` is for `branch/two`. I want to trigger `workflow-2.yml` when I push something to `branch/two` so I have this code

```
on:
  push:
    branches: 
      - branch/two
```

in `workflow-2.yml`. When i push something in `branch/two' to test,` workflow-2.yml` doesn't trigger. I've also tried

```
on:
  push:
    branches: 
      - 'branch/two'
```

but it seems to be not working. Do I have to have a workflow file in `branch/two` as well in order for it to work? Am I missing something here?

I've also checked the documentation and I think there is nothing wrong with the syntax. I've also tried adding personal access token in `workflow-2.yml`. `workflow-1.yml` is working fine because it's just

```
on: push
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in [About workflow triggers](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/triggering-a-workflow#about-workflow-triggers)

> A workflow run is triggered for any workflows that have on: values that match the triggering event. Some events also require the workflow file to be present on the default branch of the repository in order to run.

That means, when GitHub Actions evaluates the `on` directive, it checks the workflow file in the branch that is being pushed to.
If you have `workflow-2.yml` in your `main` branch but not in `branch/two`, then it will not be triggered when you push to `branch/two`, because GitHub Actions will not "see" it.

Therefore, if you want `workflow-2.yml` to run when you push to `branch/two`, you need to add the `workflow-2.yml` file to `branch/two`.

```bash
git switch branch/two
git restore --source=main .github/workflows/workflow-2.yml
git add .github/workflows/workflow-2.yml
git commit -m "Add workflow-2.yml to branch/two"
git push origin branch/two
```

Now, `workflow-2.yml` should be triggered whenever you push to `branch/two`.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your input. So I guess there is no point in trying to set up cross branch GitHub workflow if I have to put the yaml file in `branch/two' anyways. I might as well just do `on: push` on `branch/two` instead.

Comment: @Zen True, the configuration of a GitHub Actions workflow is based on the workflow files present in the same branch.